# How to compute the mean with null treated as zero

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

In Snowflake how can I return the mean of a column, where null values are treated as zero. So, if we have 3 values: 1, 2, NULL, I would like to return 1, not 1.5 as returned by AVG function.

Answer (score 6):

Using [ZEROIFNULL](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/zeroifnull.html) function:

> Returns 0 if its argument is null; otherwise, returns its argument.

```
SELECT AVG(ZEROIFNULL(col_name))
FROM tab;
```

Answer (score 4):

This can be done using `COALESCE` to replace null values with 0:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE foo AS 
  SELECT $1
    FROM VALUES ( 1 ), ( 2 ), ( NULL);
    
SELECT AVG(COALESCE($1, 0)) FROM foo;
```

Answer (score 4):

You have several options, choose one of the following:

```sql
SELECT AVG(v) AS "avg"
     , AVG(COALESCE(v, 0)) AS "avg_with_coalesce"
     , AVG(CASE WHEN v IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE v END) AS "avg_with_case"
     , AVG(IFF(v IS NULL, 0, v)) AS "avg_with_iff"
     , AVG(IFNULL(v, 0)) AS "avg_with_ifnull"
     , AVG(ZEROIFNULL(v)) AS "avg_with_zeroifnull"
  FROM VALUES (1), (2), (NULL) AS t(v);
```

Result:

| avg | avg_coalesce | avg_case | avg_iff | avg_ifnull | avg_zeroifnull |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.500000 | 1.000000 | 1.000000 | 1.000000 | 1.000000 | 1.000000 |